# How do I print a string without every third charater in python?

Tags: python, substring, character

I'm currently trying to do this challenge where it gives me a string, such as `'Python'` and I need to remove every third character, or every character which index is divisible by 3. In this example, the output would be `yton`. So far, I have the `word[::3]` part to *find* every 3rd character, but how would I take each of these and remove them from the string?

#### Code

```
word = str(input())
newWord = word[::3]
print(newWord) #for testing
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Please provide some code to help you debug ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input string is immutable, but convert it to a list and you can edit it:

```
>>> word = list(input())  # Read in a word
abcdefghijklmnop
>>> del word[::3]         # delete every third character
>>> ''.join(word)         # join the characters together for the result
'bcefhiklno'
```

Starting at a different character:

```
>>> word = list(input())
123123123123
>>> del word[2::3]
>>> ''.join(word)
'12121212'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
>>> word = 'Python For All'
>>> new_word = ''.join(character for index, character in enumerate(word) if index%3 != 0)
>>> new_word
'ytonFo Al'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
s = '0123456'
print s[::3]
# 036

# first way(understandable) create a new str
s_new = ''
for i in xrange(len(s)):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        s_new += s[i]

print s_new
# 1245

# second way
s_lst = [c if i % 3 else '' for i, c in enumerate(s)]
print s_lst
# ['', '1', '2', '', '4', '5', '']
s_new = ''.join(s_lst)
print s_new
# 1245

# you can put it in single line
s_new = ''.join([c if i % 3 else '' for i, c in enumerate(s)])
print s_new
# 1245

# third way
s_idx = filter(lambda x: x[0] % 3, enumerate(s))
print s_idx
# [(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (4, '4'), (5, '5')]
print ''.join([x[1] for x in s_idx])
# 1245
```